# WebBrowser.Navigate works over HTTP but fails for same url on HTTPS (C#)

Tags: c#, ssl, https, webbrowser-control

I have a testing environment and a production environment for my site, and I'm not sure if this is just a problem with my certificate or not. My testing environment has a real certificate that I generated using digicert, but I do see in the browser info that it says "Your connection to this site is not fully secure."

I'm using a WebBrowser to generate a page on my site and turn it into a downloadable image, here is the basic code:

```
using (var webBrowser = new WebBrowser {ScrollBarsEnabled = false, ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true}){
    webBrowser.Navigate(_url);
    while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete){
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(5);
    }

    while (!(bool)webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("getDataIsReady"))
    {
        // Exit if requested
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(15);
    }

    // Slight pause because sometimes there is a few milliseconds before the GMAP tiles are completely loaded after the "tilesloaded" event fires
    Thread.Sleep(200);

    // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
    webBrowser.Width = _width < 1 ? webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width : _width;
    webBrowser.Height = _height < 1 ? webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height : _height;

    // Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
    bitmap = new Bitmap(webBrowser.Width, webBrowser.Height);
    webBrowser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, webBrowser.Width, webBrowser.Height));
```

when I run it over http, the document loads, but over https, when I inspect `webBrowser.Document`, I see the Title is "Navigation Canceled".

Is this a problem with my cert, or with the WebBrowser method? I'm hopeful that when I push it to Prod, which has a real SSL cert, it will work, but I don't want to deploy it and then find out it doesn't work there either.

Comment: Easy way to ignore broken certs is to use Fiddler, configure it to decrypt SSL and ignore cert errors (not going to help Firefox, but should be fine for Edge/IE/Chrome and hence .Net WebBrowser ). As side effect you'll see all requests to make debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

This may due to your ssl certificate is not trusted.  Load the URL in internet explorer if the cert is not valid, add it as a trusted certificate. Then try with web browser control.